# Internal drive turns read only

Tags: permissions, mount, sudo, fstab, disk

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and have an internal 8tb harddrive which I want it to be mounted to all users on my machine both admins and not.

I've created a folder called 8tb in `/media/8tb`

Then I added the below to `/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/sda /media/8tb ext4 user,defaults 0 1
```

The harddrive keeps switching to readonly after using it for some time then when I unmount it and remount it it shows the below message asking for an admin account to mount it, not sure what the problem is?

[image]

Here is how it looks in the disks:

[image]

If I mount it with an admin account I get this error message:

[image]

Although in the sudoers file I have this added allowing the non-admin account I have to mount without sudo

```
my_non_admin_user    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/mount.cifs, /bin/mount, /bin/umount
```

I tried changing the fstab file to be like this:

```
/dev/sda /media/8tb ext4 user,defaults 0 2
```

or

```
UUID=629f755c-a29e-43bd-ad02-8deec4abdddb /media/8tb ext4 user,defaults 0 2
```

But still the same thing happens and it turns read only and

and this is the result of `ll /dev/sda`:

```
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 jun 10 22:24 /dev/sda
```

I've run `dmesg` `journalctl` and S.M.A.R.T and placed the results in this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bgw1rkbhj1vqrn0/AABGVaqh-LMoc8oAyVwqLwyIa)

I wonder what might be the reason the drive suddenly turns read only? And how to avoid this?

Comment: Did you look in your logs to see if a reason was given?  (`dmesg` or `journalctl`)

Comment: @guiverc how to check the logs? Where are they located?

Comment: either issue `dmesg` or see in `/var/log` , modern ubuntu has journalctl: https://www.linode.com/docs/quick-answers/linux/how-to-use-journalctl/

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Post the text itself.

Comment: @Pilot6 you mean the output of the journalctl?

Comment: I mean all outputs. You can copy text from a terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a sign for either

- **filesystem fault**
- **hardware damage/disconnects/timeouts**
- **undervoltage**
- **your system runs out of memory**

---

ext4 is relatively "robust" against most things  , the only thing that is likely to break is the journal

- check the output of `dmesg` and/or [journalctl](https://www.linode.com/docs/quick-answers/linux/how-to-use-journalctl/) on your console for errors
- see [if your disk reports errors via S.M.A.R.T](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-find-out-if-harddisk-failing.html)
- possibly [issue a S.M.A.R.T self test](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/SMART_tests_with_smartctl)

  ( quick-hint: gnome-disks,select disk , press `s` or select smart
  test from menu (3 bars))
- possibly **run bios/uefi system internal hard disk test**
- check for **bad connections** to the disks
- check for **undervoltage** , especially on developer boards

---

since you indicated a disk timeout:

you can increase the waiting time for disks ,command to find the timeouts :

```
 find /sys/class/scsi_generic/*/device/timeout -exec grep -H . '{}' \;
```

then you could change timeout to 3 min (as root)

```
 echo 180 > /sys/block/sda/device/timeout
```

#### !!DANGER!!

### unless this is related to excessive load,  [disk timeouts/bus-reset freezes] are a strong indicator for serious trouble like drivers  doing wrong or disk dying ( not replying because it cannot allocate the sector in given time)

#### data written during a reconnect that fails WILL BE LOST

---

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've updated my question where if I even tried remounting the drive with an admin user it fails as shown in the question. I've run `dmesg` `journalctl` and S.M.A.R.T and placed the results in this link https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bgw1rkbhj1vqrn0/AABGVaqh-LMoc8oAyVwqLwyIa?dl=0 I'd appreciate it if you could check it out?

Comment: your mount comand should be "mount /dev/sdaN" where N is partition number , your drive / sata link gets stuck and bus reset times out , is this a virtual box ? then change from sata to ide link .  also smartctl might fail when this is a usb disk

Comment: No it’s not a virtual box, and not a USB disk. Did you get the chance to check the link having the outputs of the commands you asked me?

Comment: i did look through your dmesg &screenshots  .. it might be you have bad sectors or somehthing about the sata controller is wrong

Comment: @Tak see the updated answer, maybe try to hear on the disk if there is some clicking or high frequent noise, you might try a self test/see smart values with `gnome-disks` easily

Comment: I ran `gnome-disks` and here is the result https://www.dropbox.com/s/cjpo7c0ukaqbd3l/gnome-disks.png?dl=0. do you think it is a hardware issue with the disk or something from the OS?

Comment: ( that is the start screen) , select the 8TB and either press `S` (seems standard hotkey for smart ) ,  or select it in the menu ( th three bars on top)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109292/discussion-between-tak-and-benji-over-9000-benchonaut).

Comment: Could you please check my question here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261248/mount-drive-automatically-to-all-users

Comment: @Tak "This question was voluntarily removed by its author." , did you manage this one ?